# Logic when merge two lists

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have 2 lists (DB, Heartbeat). I need to merge them into one with some rules

- if the list `DB` is empty, then add all values from the list `Heartbeat` and set `Connected` value to `true`
- if the list `Heartbeat` contains value that doesn't exists in  the list `DB`, then it should be aded to `DB` and set `Connected` value to `true`
- if the list `DB` contains a value, but the list `Heartbeat` doesn't = set `Connected` value to `false` in list `DB`

Item:

```
public class Item
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public bool Connected {get;set;}     
}
```

**First case:**

```
List<Item> db = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item { Name = "A", Connected = true },
    new Item { Name = "B", Connected = true },
    new Item { Name = "C", Connected = true }
};

List<string> heartbeat = new List<string>() { "A", "B" };
```

The result in `DB` should be:

```
A, true
B, true
C, false
```

**The second case**

```
List<Item> db = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item { Name = "A", Connected = true },
    new Item { Name = "B", Connected = false }
};

List<string> heartbeat = new List<string>() { "A", "C" };
```

The result in `DB` should be:

```
A, true
B, false
C, true
```

The last one:

```
List<Item> db = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item { Name = "A", Connected = false },
    new Item { Name = "B", Connected = false }
};

List<string> heartbeat = new List<string>() { "C", "B", "E" };
```

The result in `DB` should be:

```
A, false
B, true
C, true
E, true
```

Could you please help me implement it?
I've tried to use `Concat`, `Union` etc. but no results. I've tried so far

```
foreach(var i in heartbeat)
{
    var a = db.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == i);
    if (a == null)        
    {
        db.Add(i);
    }
    else
    {
        a.Connected = true;
    }
}

foreach(var i in db.Where(x => !heartbeat.Contains(x.Name)))
{
    i.Connected = false;
}
```

How can I improve that?

Comment: Your third output doesn't match your requirements. It seems to me that it should be false followed by three trues.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are right, my mistake, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query works according to your requirements:

```
List<Item> output =
    Enumerable
        .Concat(
            heartbeat.Select(x => new Item { Name = x, Connected = true }),
            db.Select(x => new Item { Name = x.Name, Connected = false }))
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .SelectMany(xs => xs.Take(1))
        .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with linear complexity if approached in the right way.

```
HashSet<string> heartbeat_set = new (heartbeat);
List<Item> newList = new();
foreach (var item in db)
{
    var is_heartbeat = heartbeat_set.Remove(item.Name);
    newList.Add(new Item {
        Name = item.Name, Connected = is_heartbeat && item.Connected
    });
}

foreach (var hb in heartbeat_set)
{
    newList.Add(new Item {
        Name = hb, Connected = true
    });
}
```

In this way the complexity is no more than `O(N + M)` where `N` and `M` are the size of `heartbeat` and `db`, respectively.

The construction of an `HashSet` from an `Enumerable` is a `O(N)` operation, while The `Remove` operation is constant. The code is pretty easy to understand, the only thing to explain could be `Connected = is_heartbeat && item.Connected`: basically the final `Connected` property is `true` only if the starting `Connected` property is true and there is the correspondent heartbeat. Fortunately, [`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.remove?view=net-5.0) returns `false` if the element has not been found, meaning no heartbeat.